# How is it possible to click on a button on website using VBA?

Tags: html, vba, button

I have a button that is present on a website that I want to click using VBA code. 
[image: image 1]. This is what the HTML code of the button looks like.

I wrote this piece of code to click the button

```vb
Set the_input_elements = objIE.document.getElementsByTagName("a")

For Each input_element In the_input_elements

  If input_element.className = "big_button" _
      And input_element.href = "javascript:changePageToFrontdoor(false);" Then

    input_element.Click
    Exit For

  End If

Next
```

However, this is not clicking the button. No error message. Just nothing happening with the page.

Can anyone tell me where is my error?

Thank you :)

Comment: It's possible the page is not fully loaded when your code runs.  Try adding a wait.

Answer (score 0):

Tri something like this

```
Sub Login()
    Dim IeApp As InternetExplorer
    Dim IeDoc As Object
    Dim ieTable As Object
    Set IeApp = New InternetExplorer
        IeApp.Visible = True
            IeApp.Navigate "http://yourlink.com"
            Do While IeApp.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
            Do Until IeApp.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE: DoEvents: Loop
            Set IeDoc = IeApp.document
            Set the_input_elements = IeDoc.getElementsByClassName("big_button")
            For Each input_element In the_input_elements
                If input_element.href = "javascript:changePageToFrontdoor(false);" Then
                    input_element.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next input_element
End Sub
```